# Linux Command for locating/finding a file where the filename is stored in a variable

Tags: bash, locate

I know this should be simple command but I am not able to figure out the mistake. I think it something with the syntax

So I have a file name `script.sh` which is stored in a variable `var1`. So flow goes like this

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter commit hash"
read commit
var1=`git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "$commit"`
echo $var1
locate -br "$var1"
```

The code works fine till `echo $var1`, but I am not able to find/locate the path where file exisits.

Expected output

```
script.sh
/c/training
```

Assuming script.sh is present in /c/training.

Comment: `locate` doesn't look at the "live" filesystem, it searches a list of files that's periodically regenerated by `updatedb` (which is perhaps run as a cron or systemd job).  This has the advantage of fast search speed, but the disadvantage that additions or renames since the last `updatedb` won't be reported by `locate`, while it *wilI* show files that have since been deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, make sure to use `name-only` not `name-oly`

See [`git diff-tree --name-only`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree#Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt---name-only)

That would explain why `var1` is empty.

Also, use the suggestions [from shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) for your bash script.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter commit hash"
read -r commit
var1=$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r "$commit")
echo "$var1"
locate -br "$var1"
```

Comment: Thank you, but that was just a typing error. I have edited the original post, still no output though. and `var1` does store the value.

Comment: @Nikhil Then add `-x` in your first line: `#! /bin/bash -x`: you will see what each line does.

Comment: @Nikhil Make sure to execute the script while being in the root folder of your local repository.

Comment: Did both. Still not showing the path. The script just stops after running the `echo` command.
 I went out of the local repo and tried it, errored out with "not a git repo or part...." just to cross check

Comment: Tried using the `find` command instead of `locate` after reading up on the difference between the two. 
Works now.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using the `find` command instead of `locate` after reading up on the difference between the two.
Works now.

Comment: Don't forget to look at that `-mount` (same as `-xdev`) and `-xautofs` options to `find` if you start your search from `'/'`. Or, if you know it will be somewhere under `/c`, then make sure you are using `find /c ....`